# How to rename an element name with random values inside a for-each loop in xslt?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to rename the element name based upon the value of the element while retrieving values from the root.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="key-by-company_code" match="dat:row" use="dat:company_code" />
    <xsl:template match="company_code">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="dat:rows">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="dat:row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-by-company_code', dat:company_code)[1])]">
        <xsl:element name="sae">

        <xsl:attribute name="filename">
            <xsl:value-of select="dat:company_code" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('key-by-company_code', dat:company_code)">
          <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:element name="row">
                    <xsl:element name="sae_id">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@sae_id" />
                    </xsl:element>  
            <xsl:element name="sae_date">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@sae_date" />
                    </xsl:element>
            <xsl:if test="'company_code' = local-name()">
            <xsl:if test="dat:company_code = '30'">
            <xsl:template match="company_code">
            <Co30>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </Co30>
            </xsl:template>
                    </xsl:if>  
                    </xsl:if>
            <xsl:element name="payment_type">
                      <xsl:value-of select="dat:payment_type" />
                    </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="concur_pay">

                <xsl:variable name="Concur-Pay" select="dat:concur_pay" />

                <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$Concur-Pay = '0'">N</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>Y</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>            
            </xsl:element>

           </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above is the xslt I am trying to use for the requirement but it does not work.I need to rename the element name based on the value of the element and assign the value from a different element.For eg.:- if the value of the company_code is 30 then the output should be as below

```
<sae filename="30">
<row>
<sae_id>76</sae_id>
<sae_date>2012-12-07-08:00</sae_date>
<Co30>1286.91</Co30>
<payment_type>CASH</payment_type>
<concur_pay>N</concur_pay>
<total>1286.91</total>
</row>
</sae>
```

Here the value of the element "total" should be assigned to "Co 30".Similarly if the company_code is 32 or 33 or 36 things should happen as above.

Please let me know how can I rename this element.

Comment: The provided XML isn't well-formed. A name cannot contain a space. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: `<sae filename="30">
<row>
<sae_id>76</sae_id>
<sae_date>2012-12-07-08:00</sae_date>
<Co30>1286.91</Co30>
<payment_type>CASH</payment_type>
<concur_pay>N</concur_pay>
<total>1286.91</total>
</row>
</sae>`                                                                                                                                      Please let me know if this is fine and what could be the possible way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Seems OK. Please, edit the question and place there this XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing this:

```
        <xsl:if test="'company_code' = local-name()">
        <xsl:if test="dat:company_code = '30'">
        <xsl:template match="company_code">
        <Co30>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Co30>
        </xsl:template>
                </xsl:if>  
                </xsl:if>
```

with this:

```
<!-- Ensure company_code is a valid number to prevent invalid tag names -->
<xsl:if test="number(dat:company_code) = number(dat:company_code)">
  <xsl:element name="Co{dat:company_code}">
    <xsl:value-of select="dat:total"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

You also need to remove the
`<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`
after the `<xsl:for-each>`. It is unclosed and appears to be unnecessary.